# BinaryFormatter deserialize gives SerializationException

Tags: .net, exception, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm getting an:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find
>   assembly 'myNameSpace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null

When trying to deserialize some data in another program than the program I serialized it with.

After some googling I've found out that apparently this can only be done using a shared assembly.

However, my database is full with this serialized objects, and I need a utility program to get them out. Is there a way to override this behavior and just feed it the exact same class and force it do deserialize?

---

I already found this snippet, but I don't understand how and where I should put/use this.

```
   static constructor() {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
   }

    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
        Assembly ayResult = null;
        string sShortAssemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];
         Assembly[] ayAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
         foreach (Assembly ayAssembly in ayAssemblies) {
            if (sShortAssemblyName == ayAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0]) {
                 ayResult = ayAssembly;
                 break;
            }
         }
         return ayResult;
    }
```

Comment: Referencing the original assembly in your utility app isn't an option?

Comment: @eric: some are just not answered yet...so I can not accept them. But I'll review them again to see if new answers/comments have been added

Comment: any final solutionwith full source code sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to provide a reference to the original type *somehow* so that the utility program knows how to deserialize it.

The easy way is just to add the DLL the types were originally defined in as a reference to the utility project.

The code you posted allows you to dynamically load that same DLL when the deserializer determines it can't find the type.  This is a more difficult approach (but not *that* difficult), but in both cases you will need a DLL that defines the types... so probably easiest just to statically link by adding the reference.

If your types are not currently in a DLL (e.g. if they are in an EXE), I suggest you pull the classes out of the EXE into a new DLL, and reference that DLL both from the original project and from the util project.

Comment: Great! I've actually just referenced the entire .exe just to see if it worked, and behold I could reference the namespace and the classes. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 13):

You can get around this issue without needing the DLL if you know the object...

http://spazzarama.com/2009/06/25/binary-deserialize-unable-to-find-assembly/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder(VS.71).aspx

> Use the “System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder” class. By
>   inheriting from this class it is possible to redirect all the requests
>   for types from the binary formatter to the types of your choice.

Here is a sample that will allow the types to be found in the current assembly regardless of which version of the assembly originally created the serialized stream:

```
sealed class AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {     
        String currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

        // In this case we are always using the current assembly
        assemblyName = currentAssembly;

        // Get the type using the typeName and assemblyName
        Type typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}

public static MyRequestObject Deserialize(byte[] b)
{
    MyRequestObject mro = null;
    var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(b))
    {
       // To prevent errors serializing between version number differences (e.g. Version 1 serializes, and Version 2 deserializes)
       formatter.Binder = new AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder();

       // Allow the exceptions to bubble up
       // System.ArgumentNullException
       // System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
       // System.Security.SecurityException
       mro = (MyRequestObject)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
       ms.Close();
       return mro;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I started with this, but had to heavily modify the code for my use case. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25412474/1339280

Comment: Why the `ms.Close()`? Doesn't the using statement take care of that?

Comment: yeah... that's definitely redundant, guessing copied over from a non using statement and never removed

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem and I got it working with help of the following link:
[BinaryFormatterDeserialize-not-finding-a-type](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Mar/17/BinaryFormatterDeserialize-not-finding-a-type-of-a-Plugin)

Basically what you need to do is subscribe to the AssemblyResolve event BEFORE deserializing. Then unsubscribe after deserialization..

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=
                new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
// CODE TO DESERIALIZE HERE

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

Here the method I used to resolve the Assembly:

```
static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        if(args.Name == "MY ASSEMBLY NAME"))
        {
            //Load my Assembly 
            Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom("MY ASSEMBLY PATH");
            if(assem != null)
                return assem;
        }
    }
    catch { ;}

    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
}
```

Comment: this technique worked for me when I didn't have access to the specific version of the assembly for deserialization but I knew the current version was compatible with it.

Answer (score 4):

[JTtheGeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340884/1339280) is correct that a custom `SerializationBinder` is the way to handle this problem. The example code given in that answer isn't sufficient for my use case, though. I needed something that could:

1. Handle mismatched version numbers *and* namespaces.
2. Look in all assemblies, not just the current one.
3. Still be fast enough to call 100 times per second.

This is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Company.Product.Common.Serialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A Serialization Binder that allows inexact matches (version number or namespace).
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class AllowInexactMatchSerializationBinder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
    {
        static private Dictionary<string, Type> typeBindings = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, controls the binding of a serialized object to a type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="assemblyName">Specifies the <see cref="T:System.Reflection.Assembly" /> name of the serialized object.</param>
        /// <param name="typeName">Specifies the <see cref="T:System.Type" /> name of the serialized object.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The type of the object the formatter creates a new instance of.
        /// </returns>
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            Type type;
            var assemblyQualifiedTypeName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName);

            // use cached result if it exists
            if (typeBindings.TryGetValue(assemblyQualifiedTypeName, out type))
            {
                return type;
            }

            // try the fully qualified name
            try { type = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedTypeName); }
            catch { type = null; }

            if (type == null)
            {
                // allow any assembly version
                var assemblyNameWithoutVersion = assemblyName.Remove(assemblyName.IndexOf(','));
                var assemblyQualifiedTypeNameWithoutVersion = String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyNameWithoutVersion);
                try { type = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedTypeNameWithoutVersion); }
                catch { type = null; }
            }

            if (type == null)
            {
                // check all assemblies for type full name
                try
                {
                    type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes)
                        .Where(a => a.FullName == typeName)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
                catch { type = null; }
            }

            if (type == null)
            {
                // check all assemblies for type name
                var name = typeName.Split('.').Last();
                try
                {
                    type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes)
                        .Where(a => a.Name == name)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
                catch { type = null; }
            }

            typeBindings[assemblyQualifiedTypeName] = type;
            return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the original assembly that serialized the data, then you can use a SerializationBinder or a SerializationSurrogate. These two interfaces allow you to control how types are converted between one another when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the solution answered by JTtheGeek and in order to get it work for me I had to add the following just before the statement `assemblyName = currentAssembly;`:

```
typeName = "yourNamespace.yourClassName";
```

After that it worked great!